# Diameter of set ${(a,b):0\leq a,b\leq 2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: general-topology

Set $A=\{(a,b):0\leq a,b\leq 2\}$, $a$ and $b$ both belong to $\mathbb{R}$.

What's the graph of set $A$ and what's the diameter of it?

I have the answer given on my answer sheet that the diameter is $2\sqrt2$ and the graph is a square at $(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)$.

How do I derive the solution?

As per my understanding, graph of set $A$ contains one side to infinity, points $(x,2)$, $2<x<\infty$ are also in the set. Hence the diameter is undetermined.

Does the answer sheet make sense to you or is it not rigorous enough?

Comment: The notation used is shorthand for $0\leq a\leq 2$,$0\leq b\leq 2$

Comment: There is another similar question says: the diameter of set B={(a,b):0≤a≤2,0≤b} is infinity and B is unbounded. Why the shorthand can't be used in case set B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diameter of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is the supremum of the distance between two points of this subset. Geometrically, it is the infimum of all $r$ such that a circle of radius $r$ contains the subset.

The graph is clearly a square, since $0\le a,b\le 2$ (this notation is a shorthand for $0\le a\le 2\,\text{and}\,0\le b\le 2$) and since a square of side $c$ is inscriptible in a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{c}{2}$ (half of the diagonal length), you have the answer.

Draw the situation in a cartesian plane and you will probably see it easily:

[image: Subset $A$]

Comment: I guess the actual problem is that the shorthand notation of $0\leq a,b\leq 2$ is unclear, maybe you can add this to your answer?

Comment: Better to say the diameter is the *sup* of the set of distances between all pairs of points. (As the max of that set may not exist; although it does in this case.)

Comment: @SimonS Yes, it is true, I'll edit that.

Comment: Indeed, the shorthand is not clear. I will make note on it. Because there is another similar question says: the diameter of set B={(a,b):0≤a≤2,0≤b} is infinity and B is unbounded. Why the shorthand can't be used in case set B?

Comment: The shorthand $\alpha\le a,b \le \beta$ is used only when $a$ and $b$ have the same bounds (lower bound $\alpha$ and upper bound $\beta$). In your example, $a$ has $0$ and $2$ as bounds when $b$ has $0$ as lower bound and has no upper one, so that you can't use the shorthand. I would recommand not to use it because it is quite ambiguous.